# Documentation for RocketChip-generator

Tags: rocket-chip

I recently started digging into the rocketchip generator because I want to use it for a project.
I am really new to chisel and the way that RocketChip is generated.
By now i figured out how I can configure a rocketchip and how I simulate the scala code and how rtl is generated.
However, I keep searching for documentation that explains the idea how the chip is being veified and the general architecture of the chip.

I tried to run `docs/mdoc` after starting `sbt` from the root directory however this results in several errors on the latest master branch and on v1.6 and v1.5 and I dont know if this type of documentation answers my questions.
So my question is is there an existing documentation somewhere where I missed it?
Of course I tried to google it but I do not believe that there is no documentation out there.

Thank you in advance!